# Solving 2nd order PDE and it's canonical form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this PDE
$$ u_{xx} + u_x - u_y + f(x, y) = 0$$
Where
$$f(x, y) = x + y + e^{x} cos^2(x) + 7$$
Let's "kill" $u_x$ and $u_y$ by substitution
$$u = we^{ax + by}$$
To use it, let's calculate $u_{xx}, u_x, u_y$ in terms of new function
$$u_{xx} = (w_{xx} + 2aw_x +a^2w)e^{ax + by}$$
$$u_x = (w_x +aw)e^{ax + by}$$
$$u_y = (w_y +bw)e^{ax + by}$$
And after replacing this in our PDE we get
$$(w_{xx} +(1+a)w_x + (a^2+a - b)w - w_y)e^{ax + by} +f(x, y) = 0$$
And i have chosen $a = -1$ and $b=0$ and finally we get
$$(w_{xx} - w_y)e^{-x} + f(x, y) = 0$$
And here i don't know how to move, it seems that i made PDE easier to solve, but it still looks bad, because it's no way to "kill" $w_y$, moreover, i intuitive understand that if i "kill" $w_y$ it will be may be possible to solve something that looks like $$ w_{xx} + f(x, y) = 0$$ but i don't know ho to move next, may be there is any similar questions? or any links how to be in such problem?any help will be appreciated

Comment: Shouldn't the coefficient of $w_{x}$ in the PDE by $\color{red}{2}a + 1$?